# How to fade from one video to another in ffmpeg, both audio and video

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I've been experimenting with the `xfade` (video) and `acrossfade` (audio) filters in ffmpeg to allow the 'fading' between two input videos, but I don't actually see a way to get ffmpeg to properly fade both video's video and audio without the audio desyncing.  `xfade` has an `offset` option, so if I want the first video to start a 2 second fade after 5 seconds I can say:

```
ffmpeg -i first.mp4 -i second.mp4 -filter_complex "[0v][1v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=5;[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=2:c1=tri:c2=tri" output.mp4
```

However, as you'll notice in the above, `acrossfade` has no `offset` option.  I presume what it's doing is just crossfading the audio from the very end of one video into the very beginning of the other, which will desync because the video fade is cutting in 5 seconds into the first video.

Is there a way to keep the audio and video synchronized?  Am I missing something with the `acrossfade` filter as to why it doesn't have an `offset` param, or is this just an extra feature that `xfade` has that `acrossfade` doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this isn't a particularly simple operation; it's fiddly to do with ffmpeg, though it can be done.  I'll start with the basic how-to calculate numbers, then plug them into the command necessary, then I'll explain at the end.

Calculate:

- `$$offset` = how many seconds of the first video to play before the fade transition (example: 10)
- `$$duration` = duration of the fade transition (example: 4)
- `$$trimlength` = `$$offset` + `$$duration`

Given the above variables, the following cross-fades from one input video to another input video (both the video and audio), using a standard fade transition both for video and audio which lasts for 4 seconds, with the transition starting 10 seconds into the first video:

```
ffmpeg ^
  -i first.mp4 ^
  -i second.mp4 ^
  -filter_complex "[0v][1v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=$$duration:offset=$$offset[video];[0:a]atrim=0:$$trimlength[0A];[0A][1:a]acrossfade=d=$$duration:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio]" ^
  -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" ^
  output.mp4
```

Which translates to the following command with the variables' values substituted:

```
ffmpeg ^
  -i first.mp4 ^
  -i second.mp4 ^
  -filter_complex "[0v][1v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=4:offset=10[video];[0:a]atrim=0:14[0A];[0A][1:a]acrossfade=d=4:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio]" ^
  -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" ^
  output.mp4
```

^ The above audio curves 'tri' are linear, and the audio fade may sometimes sound better with exponential curves instead; use them by specifying 'exp' instead.  Experiment with other curve types too, not to mention different video fade transition effects!

NOTE: I've found that the extra processing involved in these fades can cause ffmpeg to output a more "advanced" MP4 than the input MP4s were (such as the High 4:4:4 Profile instead of the Main Profile), which some older or more basic video playback software may not support (*ahem* Telegram's built-in video player *ahem*).  To make it output Main Profile video, add `-profile:v main -pix_fmt yuv420p`; for example:

```
ffmpeg ^
  -i first.mp4 ^
  -i second.mp4 ^
  -filter_complex "[0v][1v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=4:offset=10[video];[0:a]atrim=0:14[0A];[0A][1:a]acrossfade=d=4:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio]" ^
  -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" ^
  -profile:v main -pix_fmt yuv420p ^
  output.mp4
```

**Explanation:**
ffmpeg, without wanting to be too blunt, is a bit of a mess.  Different filters are implemented differently by different teams from other filters, resulting in both different argument syntax styles, and different features; some with more features with others, even for filters that seem like they're doing similar things and ought to have the same sorts of syntax and features.

In this instance, the `xfade` (video) filter is more capable than the `acrossfade` (audio) filter in that it can take an offset.  You can say "run 10 seconds on the first video, then do a 4 second transition to the second video, so that seconds 10-14 from the first video and seconds 0-4 from the second video are blended together with a fade effect.

The `acrossfade` filter, however, does not have the offset functionality.  You can only say "run the entire first audio minus the transition length, then do a 4 second transition to the second audio, so that seconds `($len-4)`-`$len` from the first audio and seconds 0-4 from the second audio are blended together with a fade effect.

Because you can't specify the offset option with acrossfade, you have to emulate it.  You can do this by first trimming the input audio to be the length of the desired offset plus the transition length; if you trim it to 14 seconds and specify a 4 second transition length, you'll effectively get that 10 second offset and a 4 second transition at the end, because acrossfade just takes the last 4 seconds available in the audio stream.  So, to do that, you initially pass the first audio stream through the `atrim` filter to do just that, mapping that trimmed stream to the `[0A]` handle, then pass that on to the the `acrossfade` filter.  You trim with `atrim` to the length of offset+duration, then `acrossfade` for duration.  To put it all together, map the `[video]` and `[audio]` streams at the end to produce an output.

When you're calculating how long to make the offset and transition duration for the first video, it can be useful to get the exact length of the first video so you can ensure you make your calculation *slightly shorter* than the first video length - if you want to pretty much include your entire first video in the output - to avoid an overrun.  You can use `ffprobe` to get this length like so:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 first.mp4
```

See the documentation on the two filters for more customization info:
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xfade
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#acrossfade